# I'm trying to find the sofascore endpoints

Tags: python, endpoint

I'm trying get statistics player in tournament and season actually but I not find endpoint, I tried https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/players/794839/statistics/season/41886/tournament/17 but not working and I could not find documentation for sofascore. Can somebody help me ?

Get statistics player

`https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/players/794839/statistics/season/41886/tournament/17`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the understat api, which is free and doesn't require a key and has pretty much everything sofascore does.

https://readthedocs.org/projects/understat/downloads/pdf/latest/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34852230)

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this endpoint:**

```js
https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/player/{playerID}/unique-tournament/{tournamentID}/season/{seasonID}/statistics/overall
```

Change {**player ID**}, {**Tournament ID**} and {**Season ID**}

**//**Example**: Stats of Rodri:**
https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/player/827606/unique-tournament/17/season/52186/statistics/overall

Comment: Can you share did you finde the documentation for this?

Comment: I've tried something similar for Vinicius Jr and got an error message:
https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/player/868812/unique-tournament/36/season/52376/statistics/overall

Vincius ID is 868812 (that works), but the rest of the request fails (even though La Liga's code is 36 and 52376 is the most recent season ID). See for instance: https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/tournament/36/seasons